# Explicit homotopy between $f:S^1\to S^1$ the antipodal map and the identity map

Tags: algebraic-topology

I know that $f$ is rotating $180$ degrees and the identity is rotating by $0$ degrees. How do I write down an explicit homotopy between these two maps? I know this is a stupid question but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Let the $t$th stage of the homotopy be rotation by $180t$ degrees.  More explicitly, define $H:S^1\times[0,1]\to S^1$ by $H(z,t)=e^{i\pi t}z$, considering $S^1$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.